# Geographics positions on a map using cartodb and ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cartodb

I would like to show on a map, with bullet point for instance, several geographic positions using their `longitude` and `latitude` (like on [this](http://goo.gl/Pi506S) map).
I would like to do it using `cartodb` and `ipython notebook`. I have seen on the web a lot of example but all of them are quite complicated and I am a little bit lost.

Do you have any suggestion and/or simple example that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use google map instead of cartodb with [gmaps](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmaps/0.1.6) module.